# Is there any good free website or tool to make cartoon from pictures?

Tags: software-recommendation, comics

Is there any good free website or graphic software to make cartoon from pictures of person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use Photoshop than its quite easy to make.

first of all open the pic than go to Filter/Artistic/Poster Edges.play with sliders and get the detailed output which you want.

I attached a SS to make you clear if you use Photoshop.

---

[image]

[image]

---

[you can follow this detailed tutorial if you have any confusion with photoshop](http://www.showandtell-graphics.com/cartoon-photoshop.html)

---

There are some sites which do provide to make cartoon from pictures of person

1. http://cartoon.pho.to/
2. http://kusocartoon.com/photo-to-cartoon.php
3. http://www.befunky.com/features/
4. http://www.cartoonme.com/en/
5. http://cartoonize.net/
6. http://www.dumpr.net/sketch.php
7. http://cartoonyourselffree.com/

---

Software which you can download and use :

1. http://download.cnet.com/Photo-to-Cartoon/3000-2191_4-10631533.html
2. http://cartoon-maker.en.softonic.com

   Hope this help

---

Comment: i recommend you to use befunky its awesome